# My Google Nexus S won't connect to network

Tags: calls, connection-issues, samsung-nexus-s, mobile-network

I have a problem with my Google Nexus S. Yesterday I was out in the city and my battery meanwhile died and the phone shutdown. The next day when I charged the phone, I  noticed that it is showing no signal even when there is signal. I've turned it off and on a couple of times. I also tried a different SIM from a different service and it didn't show signal either! Also I tired those SIM cards on a different phone and it works.

The big mystery for me is that until the battery died yesterday I made calls from this phone with no problems, and until now I never had problems with this phone.

When I go to `Settings` -> `About phone` -> `Status`, I see that Network shows *unknown* and Service state shows *out of service*. Is there anything I can try resetting?

Comment: Yes I did, but with no result

Comment: Yea.. I realized that later, as you mentioned that you tried different SIM as well. Obviously, you had to remove SIM and battery. Silly me!

Comment: Your SIM tray may have some problems. See if the connectors (not sure what it's called) are not bended. Try lifting the connectors up a bit. This solves problem in most cases. Also, blow some air to de-dust it.

Comment: I also had this problem few months ago, but it was fixed very quickly with an update from Google (I was lucky with that update from Google). From what I observe (from my experience) at Google Nexus S, this problem appears when battery die and the phone it shutdown. And I guess that this a soft problem.

Comment: Ohk.. If that is the case then a reset might help. You can also try flashing a custom ROM, if you are comfortable.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your issue? If so, how?